# Android scrollbars appear inside views after opening preferencescreen

Tags: android, preferencescreen

I use navigation architecture component and if I navigate to the settings page and then I go back then lines and scrollbars appear on views. The PreferenceScreen is very simple only contains a ListPreference.

[image]
[image]

**SettingsFragment:**

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
    init()
}

private fun init() {
    (activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.supportActionBar?.show()
    activity?.fab?.visibility = View.GONE
    (activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.nav_view?.visibility = View.GONE

    activity?.app_bar?.setExpanded(true, true)

    val toolbarParams = activity?.toolbar?.layoutParams as AppBarLayout.LayoutParams
    toolbarParams.scrollFlags = 0
} }
```

**xml:**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory app:title="General">

    <ListPreference
        app:key="app_theme_color"
        app:title="Theme"
        app:defaultValue="black"
        app:entries="@array/color_entries"
        app:entryValues="@array/color_values"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: Are they scroll markers?

Comment: Yes, I think they are.